# Error when I subtract two numbers read by Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, debugging, rounding

I have this question, two variables read by Excel sheet:

```
APPOGGIO_1 =0,2  
APPOGGIO_3 =0,2
```

If this value is read by Excel I have the situation in the image:

[image]

obviously if value is assigned another way the result is `0`.

Why in Debug I view correct variable values and the result is incorrect? 
The Round function resolves the problem, but is that the correct way?

```
  VALORE = Round((APPOGGIO_1 - APPOGGIO_3), 2)
```

Comment: See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/78113).

Comment: Do you have all the variables set? what is N1,B, where is the sheet indicated? you only have two variables Dimmed as Doubles, the other 2 are variants because you never dimmed them as Double

Comment: N1,B are indexes in Excel sheet